# Fixed div positioned Issue while reaching footer by scroll if the fixed div height is more than the footer height

Tags: jquery

When the user start the window scroll, while reaching footer the fixed positioned div (which is fixed at the bottom of the window) will changed to relative without any jerk effect. Now it is working fine when fixed div height less than the footer height. But, if fixed div height is more than the footer height we are unable to change the fixed div position to relative. Please find the below [JSFIDDLE link](http://jsfiddle.net/enULV/108/).

```
  function checkOffset() {
    if ($('#footer_border').offset().top + $('#footer_border').height() >= $('#footer').offset().top - 10) $('#footer_border').css('position', 'relative');
    if ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() < $('#footer').offset().top) $('#footer_border').css('position', 'fixed'); // restore when you scroll up
}
$(document).scroll(function() {
    checkOffset();
});
```

Please let me know if any solution without giving any fixed height to the fixed div.